# Providing git remote with SSH arguments?

Tags: shell, ssh, git, arguments

For some reason, my console hangs if I try to run any `ssh` command. For example:

`ssh user@server date` will hang,

`ssh -f user@server date` works.

If I want to include the `-f` argument in a `git remote` URL, how would I do so? Right now I have:

`git remote add origin ssh://user@server/home/user/repo/mine.git` but if I try to push/pull from it, it hangs. I would like to add the `-f` argument to this URL because I suspect it will solve the problem.

How do I tell `git` to use the `-f` argument when calling `ssh`?

Answer (score 4):

From the fine manual for `git(1)` we find

```
   GIT_SSH, GIT_SSH_COMMAND
       If either of these environment variables is set then git fetch and
       git push will use the specified command instead of ssh when they
       need to connect to a remote system. The command will be given
       exactly two or four arguments: the username@host (or just host)
       from the URL and the shell command to execute on that remote
       system, optionally preceded by -p (literally) and the port from the
       URL when it specifies something other than the default SSH port.

       $GIT_SSH_COMMAND takes precedence over $GIT_SSH, and is interpreted
       by the shell, which allows additional arguments to be included.
       $GIT_SSH on the other hand must be just the path to a program
       (which can be a wrapper shell script, if additional arguments are
       needed).
```

So therefore the simplest via shell interpretation is

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -f" git push ...
```

or a full wrapper via `GIT_SSH`.

Comment: How do I know if git is using the environmental variable? If I do `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -f" git push origin master` it still hangs, so I don't know if the `-f` was the source of the original problem or not. If I do `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh adslkfjalskdf -asfd -adsf" git push origin master` I don't get an error, so it seems like `git` is not using the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable.

Comment: A straightforward test of `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v -v -v" git push ...` shows the verbose output from SSH.

Comment: Interesting, I get prompted for my password (like always), but it hangs with no verbose output when doing `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v -v -v" git push origin master`